# Why the first code work and second give wrong output?

Tags: c, output

This is the first code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()  
{   
   short int a;
   unsigned short int l;
   scanf("%d%u",&a,&l);
   printf("%d %u",a,l);
   return 0;
}
```

If I give the input(may be any other input)

```
5
9
```

The output is

```
0 9
```

The second code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   short int a;
   unsigned short int l;
   scanf("%u%d",&l,&a);
   printf("%d %u",a,l);
   return 0;
}
```

If I give the output (may be any other input)

```
9
5
```

The output is

```
5 9
```

Why `scanf("%d%u",&a,&l);` do not work and `scanf("%u%d",&l,&a);` works?

Comment: Because `%u` and `%d` are for normal `int`, not `short int`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Then how this worked in the first case? Or he got lucky?

Comment: Neither works since they both invoke undefined behavior for the reason that Oli provides.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun it is undefined behavior, he is using memory outside the allocated for the variables. He got lucky.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun: As this is UB, I'd imagine it's just chance.

Comment: That's what I thought.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a wrong specifier for a data type invokes [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Result may be expected or unexpected.

### C11:7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> (p9) If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

and about `h`:  p(7)

> `h`   Specifies that a following `d, i, o, u, x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a
> `short int` or `unsigned short int` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `short int` or `unsigned short int` before printing); or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `short int` argument.

Use `h` before `%d` and `%u` for `short` type data.

```
scanf("%hd %hu",&a,&l);
printf("%hd %hu",a,l);
```

Comment: It's unnecessary for `printf`, though, due to default argument promotions.  (although I'd argue that it's good for consistency...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; But no harm in doing so :)

Comment: @user3162531; Read the very first line of my answer.

Comment: but still why this problem is only with %d not with %u

Comment: @user3162531; I already explained that this is because the behavior of your program is not defined.